# Read line and change the line that not consist of certain words and not end with dot

Tags: php

I wanna read some text files in a folder line by line. for example of 1 txt :

```
Fast and Effective Text Mining Using Linear-time Document Clustering
Bjornar Larsen WORD2 Chinatsu Aone
SRA International AK, Inc.
4300 Fair Lakes Cow-l Fairfax, VA 22033

{bjornar-larsen, WORD1
```

I wanna remove line that does not contain of words = `word`, `word2`, `word3`, and does not end with dot `.`

so. from the example, the result will be :

```
Bjornar Larsen WORD2 Chinatsu Aone
SRA International, Inc.
{bjornar-larsen, WORD1
```

I am confused, hw to remove the line? it that possible? or can we replace them with a space?

here's the code :

```
$url = glob($savePath.'*.txt');
foreach ($url as $file => $files) {
    $handle = fopen($files, "r") or die ('can not open file');
    $ori_content= file_get_contents($files);
    foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $ori_content) as $buffer){
        $pos1 = stripos($buffer, $word1);
        $pos2 = stripos($buffer, $word2);
        $pos3 = stripos($buffer, $word3);
        $last = $str[strlen($buffer)-1];//read the las character
        if (true !== $pos1 OR true !== $pos2 OR true !==$pos3 && $last != '.'){
        //how to remove
        }
    }
}
```

please help me, thank you so much :)

Comment: if you use `file($files)` instead of `file_get_contents($files)`, an `array` of lines will be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a `!== true` comparison to test the return-value of the `stripos`. `!== true` means "is not absolutely equal-to the boolean value true". The return-value of `stripos` is numeric, unless the word doesn't exist, in which case it's `false`. In other words, your condition is always false.

Try updating it to use `=== false` instead. Also, you're using `OR` in between each; Your example shows that it needs to only contain 1 of them - so if you're checking that "none of them were found", you'll need to use `&&` for everything:

```
if (($pos1 === false) && ($pos2 === false) && ($pos3 === false) && ($last != '.'))
```

Regarding "how to remove the line", you'll need to keep a list of all lines you want to keep. This means, we'll actually want to *flip* the condition above to use `!== false` and an `||` between everything (because we want to keep all lines that match any rule).

Try something like this:

```
$url = glob($savePath.'*.txt');
foreach ($url as $file => $files) {
    $handle = fopen($files, "r") or die ('can not open file');
    $ori_content= file_get_contents($files);
    $linesToKeep = array(); // list of all lines that match our rules
    foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $ori_content) as $buffer){
        $pos1 = stripos($buffer, $word1);
        $pos2 = stripos($buffer, $word2);
        $pos3 = stripos($buffer, $word3);
        $last = $str[strlen($buffer)-1];

        if (($pos1 !== false) || ($pos2 !== false) || ($pos3 !== false) || ($last == '.')) {
            $linesToKeep[] = $buffer; // save this line
        }
    }
    // process list of lines for this file;
    // file_put_contents($files, join("\r\n", $linesToKeep)); // write back to file
    // $lines = join("\r\n", $linesToKeep); // convert to string to manipulate
}
```

Now, you'll have every line that matches your ruleset in the `$linesToKeep` array. You can convert this back to a string with `$lines = join("\r\n", $linesToKeep);`, or iterate through it and process it however you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Nice approach... But you can use `arrays` to read in your file and put it your file. Till now it is fine.

#### PS: There can be better ways to do...

```
$url = glob($savePath.'*.txt');
foreach ($url as $file => $files) {
    $handle = fopen($files, "r") or die ('can not open file');
    $ori_content= file_get_contents($files);

    # Declare a variable array to store the contents.
    $fileContents = array();

    foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $ori_content) as $buffer){
        $pos1 = stripos($buffer, $word1);
        $pos2 = stripos($buffer, $word2);
        $pos3 = stripos($buffer, $word3);
        $last = $str[strlen($buffer)-1];//read the las character
        if (($pos1 !== false) || ($pos2 !== false) || ($pos3 !== false) || ($last == '.')){
            $fileContents[] = $buffer;
        }
    }

    # Put the contents
    file_put_contents($file, implode(PHP_EOL, $fileContents);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$url = glob($savePath.'*.txt');
foreach ($url as $file => $files) {
  $lines = file($files);
  foreach ($lines as $key=>$line) {
    if (!preg_match('/(word|word2|word3)/i', $line) && substr($line, -1) != '.') {
      unset($lines[$key]);
    }
  }
  $ori_content = implode("\n", $lines);
}
```

Comment: i am surprised. this code run very fast (the fastest). thanks :)

Comment: @igo In all the other answers a redundant `fopen` call is being made before `file_get_contents`. That would explain the drop in their performance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a secondary buffer.

```
$url = glob($savePath.'*.txt');
foreach ($url as $file => $files) {
    $handle = fopen($files, "r") or die ('can not open file');
    $ori_content= file_get_contents($files);
    /* Create our second buffer */
    $buffer2 = "";
    foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $ori_content) as $buffer){
        $pos1 = stripos($buffer, $word1);
        $pos2 = stripos($buffer, $word2);
        $pos3 = stripos($buffer, $word3);
        $last = $str[strlen($buffer)-1];//read the last character
        /* This will only execute if the three words and a trailing period are _not_ found */
        if ($pos1 === false && $pos2 === false && $pos3 === false && $last != '.') {
            $buffer2 .= $buffer . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
echo $buffer2;
```

Comment: hmm.. I've tried that. The result seems still wrong. but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Another user mentioned the `!==` issue that was present in your code. Changing that should give you the same correct logic in your comparisons. I'll edit my answer to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use explode:

```
$handle = fopen($files, "r") or die ('can not open file');
$ori_content = file_get_contents($files);

$lines = explode ( '\n' , $ori_content );

foreach ( $lines AS $line )
{
 if (strpos ( $line , 'word' ) !== false OR strpos ( $line , 'word2' ) !== false OR strpos ( $line , 'word3' ) !== false OR substr ( $line , -1 ) == '.')
  {
   $newParagraph = $line . '\n';
  }
}

echo $newParagraph;
```

Much simpler than what you were trying to do.